# Wi-Fi Regulatory changes between Ubuntu 20.10 and 21.04 prevent airmon-ng from operating in 6 GHz band?

Tags: iwlwifi, airmon-ng

I have a Ubuntu 20.10 system that supports airmon-ng for packet capture with Wireshark in the 6 GHz band:

```
++ sudo airmon-ng start wlp2s0 6335

PHY Interface Driver Chipset

phy0 wlp2s0 iwlwifi Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
(mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlp2s0 on [phy0]wlp2s0mon)
(mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlp2s0)

++ iwconfig
wlp2s0mon  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:6.335 GHz  Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

I have an identical notebook with 21.04 that will connect as a client, and operate on 6 GHz channels by running wpa_supplicant from the terminal.
`sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlp2s0 -c /home/me/wpa_sae_config.conf -ddsBtK -g /tmp/wpa_global -G me`

However it will not load airmon-ng:

```
$ sudo airmon-ng start wlp2s0 6335
phy0 wlp2s0 iwlwifi Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)

Error setting channel: kernel reports: Channel is disabled
command failed: Invalid argument (-22)
Unable to set channel/frequency 6335, most likely it is outside of regulatory domain
```

Both systems `/etc/default/crda` file had the line `REGDOMAIN=` I changed the 21.04 system to `REGDOMAIN=US` but it made no difference in airmon-ng ability to use 6 GHz.
Both systems have the Intel AX-210 and have identical drivers as reported by `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-051100-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.uc
```

Are there parallel systems for regulatory domains and airmon-ng is using a different system than wpa_supplicant? Where does the underlying data reported by `iw reg get` come from?

Ubuntu 21.04 - airmon-ng does not support 6 GHz:

```
me@Latitude-7480:~$ iw reg get
global
country US: DFS-FCC
(2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
(5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
(5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
(5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
(5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW
(5850 - 5895 @ 40), (N/A, 27), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
me@Latitude-7480:~$
```

Ubuntu 20.10 - airmon-ng works in 6 GHz:

```
me@Latitude-7480:~$ iw reg get
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
(2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
(57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
phy#0 (self-managed)
country US: DFS-UNSET
(2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
(2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
(2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
(5170 - 5190 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS
(5190 - 5210 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS
(5210 - 5230 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS
(5230 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS
(5250 - 5270 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5270 - 5290 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5290 - 5310 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5310 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5490 - 5510 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5510 - 5530 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5530 - 5550 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5550 - 5570 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5570 - 5590 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5590 - 5610 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5610 - 5630 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5630 - 5650 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5650 - 5670 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5670 - 5690 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5690 - 5710 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5710 - 5730 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5735 - 5755 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ
(5755 - 5775 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ
(5775 - 5795 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ
(5795 - 5815 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ
(5815 - 5835 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
(5945 - 5965 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5965 - 5985 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5985 - 6005 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6005 - 6025 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6025 - 6045 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6045 - 6065 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6065 - 6085 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6085 - 6105 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6105 - 6125 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6125 - 6145 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6145 - 6165 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6165 - 6185 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6185 - 6205 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6205 - 6225 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6225 - 6245 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6245 - 6265 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6265 - 6285 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6285 - 6305 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6305 - 6325 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6325 - 6345 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6345 - 6365 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6365 - 6385 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6385 - 6405 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6405 - 6425 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6425 - 6445 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6445 - 6465 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6465 - 6485 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6485 - 6505 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6505 - 6525 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6525 - 6545 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6545 - 6565 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6565 - 6585 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6585 - 6605 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6605 - 6625 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6625 - 6645 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6645 - 6665 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6665 - 6685 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6685 - 6705 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6705 - 6725 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6725 - 6745 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6745 - 6765 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6765 - 6785 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6785 - 6805 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6805 - 6825 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6825 - 6845 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6845 - 6865 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6865 - 6885 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6885 - 6905 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6905 - 6925 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6925 - 6945 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6945 - 6965 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6965 - 6985 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(6985 - 7005 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(7005 - 7025 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(7025 - 7045 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(7045 - 7065 @ 1180), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(7065 - 7085 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
(7085 - 7105 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
(7105 - 7125 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
me@Latitude-7480:~$
```

Comment: I know nothing about it so this could be wrong, but I'd assume the differences lie in the kernel being used (*kernel modules are of course related to kernel itself*); ie. 5.8 for 20.10 and 5.11 for 21.04.  I suspect the answer is thus an older kernel; I'd for example try Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the GA kernel (ie. 5.4; the HWE 5.8 kernel of 20.04.2 will upgrade to 5.11 first update) and consider the LTS if you need that function, it'll have older code too - https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.6+git20210130.91820bc-1/changelog if that's the issue)

Comment: Please supply some info on the 6 frequency. I can only find info on 5 and 2.4

Comment: @David - search on "Wi-Fi 6E". In particular, the Intel AX-210 module supports it.  It requires the latest Wi-Fi features such as WPA3, PMF, and OWE.  I have been able to get it to work on 21.04 by disabling Network Manager, but now I find airmon-ng doesn't work.  airmon-ng works on 20.10, but it won't support network connectivity.  Search for my (mostly unanswered) posts on this forum for more information.

Comment: @guiverc - The issue is Wi-Fi functionality in terms of regulatory domain support for a new band. Maybe the kernel has regressed in 21.04, but hopefully there is interest in getting it fixed. For example, if 5 GHz Wi-Fi stopped working in a Ubuntu release, the solution would not be to use an older kernel.  Since 21.04 can associate and connect in 6 GHz when configured manually, there seems to be an issue in the regulatory domain information reported - I'm looking for guidance on finding the root cause, whether it is the driver, the kernel, or something else.